# Error converting PNG to TIFF-Java

Tags: java, png, tiff, javax.imageio, jai

HI I am working on the following snippet which is supposed to convert my png file to tiff.

```
            String fileName = "4848970_1";
            // String fileName = "color";
            String inFileType = ".PNG";
            String outFileType = ".TIFF";

            File fInputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\image2.png");
            InputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fInputFile));
            ImageReaderSpi spi = new PNMImageReaderSpi();
            ImageReader reader = spi.createReaderInstance();
            ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(fis);
            reader.setInput(iis, true);
            BufferedImage bi = reader.read(0);

            int[] xi = bi.getSampleModel().getSampleSize();

            for (int i : xi) {
                System.out.println("bitsize " + i);
            }

            ImageWriterSpi tiffspi = new TIFFImageWriterSpi();
            TIFFImageWriter writer = (TIFFImageWriter) tiffspi.createWriterInstance();

            // TIFFImageWriteParam param = (TIFFImageWriteParam) writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
            TIFFImageWriteParam param = new TIFFImageWriteParam(Locale.US);
            String[] strings = param.getCompressionTypes();
            for (String string : strings) {
                System.out.println(string);
            }

            //param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            //param.setCompressionType("LZW");

            File fOutputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\" + fileName + outFileType);
            OutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fOutputFile));
            ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(fos);

            writer.setOutput(ios);
            writer.write(null, new IIOImage(bi, null, null), param);

            ios.flush();
            writer.dispose();
            ios.close();
```

But this gives me following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: What in the stream isn't a PNM image.
    at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.pnm.PNMImageReader.readHeader(PNMImageReader.java:187)
    at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.pnm.PNMImageReader.read(PNMImageReader.java:301)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.imageconv.TiffImage.main(TiffImage.java:40)
```

Is it that its unable to read the PNG file or it recognises it as a non png file.Am I wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read a PNG image as if it was a PNM image. These two file formats have nothing in common; hence the error.

Comment: So how can I tweak the program to make it read PNG file and convert?

Comment: You can read PNG images directly with ImageIO.read:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html